# JFrame appears empty and minimised

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

I am trying to write a small GUI program that consist of one `JComboBox` that has to paint the `ContentPane` with a color chosen from the combobox.

I do not know why it doesn't work as it is supposed to. When I start my main method it produces an empty JFrame even without the comboBox, which I know that I had added to the JFrame.

This is my main method:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class TestRGBComboBox {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new RgbComboBoxFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

this is my JFrame class

```
public class RgbComboBoxFrame extends JFrame{
   private static final int FRAME_WIDTH = 300;
   private static final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 300;
   private JComboBox colorComboBox;
   private ActionListener listener;

public void RgbComboBoxFrame() {

    colorComboBox = new JComboBox();
    colorComboBox.addItem("RED");
    colorComboBox.addItem("GREEN");
    colorComboBox.addItem("BLUE");
    colorComboBox.setEditable(true);
    listener = new AddListener();
    paintContentPane();
    createPanel();
    setSize(FRAME_WIDTH,FRAME_HEIGHT);
}
class AddListener implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
        paintContentPane();
    }
}

private void paintContentPane(){
    Color c = (Color)colorComboBox.getSelectedItem();

    getContentPane().setBackground(c);
}
private void createPanel(){
    JPanel controlPanel = new JPanel();
    colorComboBox.addActionListener(listener);
    controlPanel.add(colorComboBox);
    add(controlPanel,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although all the code is there to create the panel and add things to it you never call them. `public void RgbComboBoxFrame(){}` should be a constructor and therefore written as `public RgbComboBoxFrame(){}`

Comment: I see know! I dont know why I even put void in the constructor declaration! Thanks man!

Comment: @BogGogo happens to everybody!